# How can I share control-specific event handlers project-wide?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, event-handling, keypress

I can code an event to limit textbox entries to decimal values like so:

```
private void txtbxPlatypus_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args)
{
    const int BACKSPACE = 8;
    const int DECIMAL_POINT = 46;
    const int ZERO = 48;
    const int NINE = 57;
    const int NOT_FOUND = -1;

    int keyvalue = (int)args.KeyChar; // not really necessary to cast to int

    if ((keyvalue == BACKSPACE) || ((keyvalue >= ZERO) && (keyvalue <= NINE))) return;
    // Allow the first (but only the first) decimal point
    if ((keyvalue == DECIMAL_POINT) && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(".") == NOT_FOUND)) return;
    // Allow nothing else
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

...and then have other TextBoxes on the page with the same entry-filtering requirement attach to that event handler:

```
txtbxSeat.KeyPress += txtbxPlatypus_KeyPress;
txtbxLunch.KeyPress += txtbxPlatypus_KeyPress;
```

However, what if I want to share such a handler project-wide, rather than have to reproduce on it on each page that has TextBoxes whose input needs to be restricted in this way?

Is there a way to set up "global" (project-wide) event handler delegates that can be used from any form in the project?

### UPDATE

This does work:

```
public static class SandBoxUtils
{
    public static void DecimalsOnlyKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args)
    {
        // same code as above in txtbxPlatypus_KeyPress()
    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBoxBaroqueMelodies.KeyPress += new 
        System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(SandBoxUtils.DecimalsOnlyKeyPress);
}
```

...but it smells a bit fishy to me. Is this anything "wrong" (or dangerous) about doing this?

Comment: Create own `textbox` control derived from `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` add your event handler. Use your own textbox for decimal input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create own class derived from `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`
Add your event handler for `KeyPress` event in the constructor
After building project new control must appear in the controls toolbox in Visual Studio,
from there you can just drag it to the form and use...

```
class TextBoxDecimal : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    const int BACKSPACE = 8;
    const int DECIMAL_POINT = 46;
    const int ZERO = 48;
    const int NINE = 57;
    const int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    const char DECIMALSEPARATOR = '.';     

    public TextBoxDecimal() :base()
    {
        this.KeyPress += TextBoxDecimal_KeyPress;
    }

    void TextBoxDecimal_KeyPress(object sender, 
                                 System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int keyvalue = (int)e.KeyChar; // not really necessary to cast to int

        if ((keyvalue == TextBoxDecimal.BACKSPACE) || ((keyvalue >= TextBoxDecimal.ZERO) && (keyvalue <= TextBoxDecimal.NINE))) return;
        // Allow the first (but only the first) decimal point
        if ((keyvalue == TextBoxDecimal.DECIMAL_POINT) && ((sender as TextBoxDecimal).Text.IndexOf(TextBoxDecimal.DECIMALSEPARATOR) == NOT_FOUND)) return;
        // Allow nothing else
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know your way is probably "the" way, but I posted a tip on my "backdoor way" here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/841727/How-to-Limit-TextBox-Entries-to-Decimal-or-Integer. I find an advantage is you don't have to have multiple controls - one for decimals, one for ints, one for duckbilled platypi (or whatever), &c.

Comment: Why not having multiple controls for every type is advantage? Custom controls give more benefits if you continue developing this approach. For example you can add `Property` which return already parsed value from string(`.Text`) to type of the custom control(`Decimal`).